# Running rocket.chat on docker composer. Where are source codes?

Tags: meteor, docker-compose, rocket.chat

This is probably a stupid question but I am running rocket.chat deployed w/ docker compose. I'm trying to customize the app but I don't know where to access the source codes. I don't really have full grasp of what docker is. Their docs are too confusing for me to understand. Any help? Can anyone direct me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the files are stored on a folder that is specified in the Dockerfile. In the case of Rocket.Chat, this is the /app folder, inside the container.

I strongly suggest you **do not** edit source files directly inside your docker container. Rocket.Chat files inside a container are a **compiled** version and not the original source files.

If you still need access to that container files, you can access your container by running:

`docker exec -it _your_container_name_ /bin/sh`

Comment: Thank you for your response. But if I wanted to customize my rocket.chat app, what would be the best solution?

Comment: The best would be not use docker, especially the ones provided by Rocket.Chat. They are for deployment, not development. There are multiple options if you want to make changes to the source code. One of them is cloning the repository from github and running through meteor. If you **really** need to use Docker, you can run the meteor docker and map a volume to a local directory, where you'd have your code.

Comment: gotcha. Thank you very much!